# Density plot of electric field magnitudes due to 2 point charges

Tags: python, matplotlib, density-plot

The two point charges (1 C and -1 C) and 10 cm away at (-5,0) and (5,0) respectively. I am attempting to make a density plot of the calculated electric field magnitudes of the surrounding areas on a 100cm x 100cm plane.

My code produces the following image. [Density Plot of Surrounding Electric Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh9OK.jpg) Would this be a correct result? I am also curious as to how I could display a 100x100 grid for the plane present. I would be grateful for any additional suggestions.

```
## Function for electric field magnitude
def elec_field_mag(q_1, q_2, x, y):
    k = 9e13
    r_1 = np.sqrt(((x+5)**2)+(y**2))
    r_2 = np.sqrt(((x-5)**2)+(y**2))
    if r_1 == 0:
        partial_x = -k*((q_2*(x-5))/(r_2**3))
        partial_y = -k*y*((q_2)/(r_2**3))
    elif r_2 == 0:
        partial_x = -k*((q_1*(x+5))/(r_1**3))
        partial_y = -k*y*(q_1/(r_1**3))
    else:
        partial_x = -k*((q_1*(x+5))/(r_1**3) + (q_2*(x-5))/(r_2**3))
        partial_y = -k*y*((q_1)/(r_1**3) + (q_2)/(r_2**3))
    magnitude = np.sqrt(partial_x**2 + partial_y**2)

    return magnitude

grid_points = 100 # 1cm spaced points on a 100x100 grid
elec_potentials = np.empty([grid_points,grid_points],float)
elec_field_magnitudes = np.empty([grid_points,grid_points], float)

for i in range(grid_points):
    for j in range(grid_points):
        x = i-50
        y = j-50
        elec_field_magnitudes[i,j] = elec_field_mag(1,-1,x,y)
        r_1 = np.sqrt(((x+5)**2)+(y**2))
        r_2 = np.sqrt(((x-5)**2)+(y**2))
        elec_potentials[i,j] = potential_calc(1,-1,r_1,r_2)

## Now to make a visual of the surrounding electric fields from the calculated gradient
plt.imshow(enter image description here='hot',extent=[-50,50,-50,50])
plt.grid(color='w',linewidth=0.3, markevery=(0,10))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```